# SPSS version 22 ERROR: attempt to connect to a remote server failed

Tags: windows-7, installation, license

If anyone can help, I'm at my wits end here and my class starts Monday.

I have installed SPSS statistics 22 on my Win7 Home 64-bit SP 1 and it will not run. I am on an HP Pavilion dv7 with tons of RAM and disk.

Authorized copy (not network) standalone install with the 20-character authentication key.

I've been with IBM's ECuRep support for SPSS and still the software will not run (not that they were really any help). I'm working on this problem for 3 weeks now.

The error on startup: "Attempt to connect to a remote server failed inet:Local Computer: 0"

I have purchased the software twice from two separate vendors, neither have been any help. Looking for ANY advice that may help. This is the student Version 22 standard Grad Pack.

thanks, John

Comment: Have you seen this: http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/SPSS21-Error-Attempt-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-failed-inet-local-computer-0-td5718367.html ?

Comment: How about this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21489528 ? (Short version: ensure firewall isn't blocking it).

Comment: "I'm working on this problem for 3 weeks now."  What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: thanks for replying techie007. unfortunately this is an unbearably long story. I'll try to summarize: Yes I've seen both the support doc and the spssx discussion. at the bottom of the spssx discussion you'll see my question, was it resolved? it was not. I worked directly with spss student support on several approaches including shutting down my AV and firewall completely and connecting to the raw internet. fail. if I miss this class, I'll be a semester out of sequence. tomorrow i'm buying a new computer. a $1200 spend to solve a $7000 future tuition problem.

Comment: Before you go buying a new computer, did you try reinstalling Windows from scratch and ensure all your drivers are up-to-date?  Seems less expensive. :)  Also, have you tried the same install files/procedures on another computer?  Perhaps it's not a problem with your computer at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running this command in the terminal:

`sudo /Applications/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/20/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/MacOS/stats`

You can also make a different user account with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a problem with A firewall. I was trying to run SPSS 22 onto a corporate windows 7 machine.

The problem lies with an incoming connection from your own PC. There is an option in SPSS that allows you to connect to a "teamwork server". Since an SPSS install installs every component but activates a component through licensing, a dummy server is installed on your machine when installing the client. The client then tries to connect to itself (localhost or 127.0.0.1).

If you have any kind of firewall or virus protection (in my case McAfee host intrusion prevention) it can block this action because there is an incoming connection (outgoing is usually less of a problem).

I would advise to turn of any and all protection you have on your computer (while not being connected over cable or wifi) to see if this helps.

Verified offenders:

- Windows Firewall
- Windows Bitdefender
- McAfee (enterprise with host intrusion)

Creating an exception rule for `.../SPSS/VERSION/stats.exe` *and* `/spssengine.exe` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem cost me two days, but this is the solution.

The problem is that 'statistics' and 'spssengine' processes are being bound to different versions of TCP/IP (v4 vs. v6), via MS support site. I used a fix to prefer v4 and the problem was solved.

Cheers,
E.